# Is the BAWSAQ stock market separate for different platforms?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Is the BAWSAQ stock market in GTA V, a market which is based on the actions of players online, separate for different platforms?  Like, is the market on PC separate from the market on XBox One?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikia](http://gta.wikia.com/Bawsaq.com):

> The site is linked directly to the Rockstar Games Social Club and is totally driven by the community, **so stocks can have different values depending of with platform the game is being played**.

So **yes**, they are separated, as the player bases are separated.

Comment: That was fast, thanks!  The reason I'm wondering is because I've heard that when it was first launched, Ammunation stocks shot up because everyone was buying weapons and stuff.

Comment: "Totally driven by the community" is entirely untrue of course. But that doesn't affect the point of the answer.